# Logging Interface Activity - Java

Tags: java, logging, interface

I'd like to know how I can log user activities in Java, I mean, the button the user clicked or the key that was pressed, without adding code to the original source code.

I'd really appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have success running the program with an [agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that calls [Toolkit.addAWTEventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29).